# ASP.NET Linq to SQL issue

Tags: c#, asp.net

What is the issue behind this i don't know every thing is working fine on local IIS but when i upload it to my web server i am facing this problem i tried every method but nothing found can some one tell me why its appearing all files are uploaded including dbml designer and cs

http://lotterynext.com/ilp/pub/ here is the live error

```
Compilation Error
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required
to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and
modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MasterClassDataContext'    
could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Source Error:

Line 24:  try
Line 25:  {
Line 26:    MasterClassDataContext db = new MasterClassDataContext();
Line 27: 
Line 28:    var qry = from m in db.tblmenus

Source File: d:\home\lotterynext.com\wwwroot\ilp\pub\HomeStyleMaster.Master.cs  Line: 26
```

Comment: It actually tells you the problem in the compilation error `are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?`. Did you really need to post this as a question on SO?

Comment: Is there any link regarding how to create linq to sql deployment actually i am doing it for first time project is almost ready but i am unable to deploy because of this issue

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have used the proper using statement in your .cs file

If Yes then it is the problem with your reference dll. Upload the proper reference dll file to your server.

Comment: First of all thank you very much for your reply .dbml and its correspondence files are uploaded already can you tell any reference url regarding this may be i had done mistake in publishing is there any tutorial regarding link to sql web application deployment?

Comment: Please share any link regarding linq to sql deployment i didn't find any useful link yet